# Decomposition of power consumption using wavelet analysis

Tags: wavelet, decomposition

I'm doing a project of decomposing the total power consumption signal to identify/ recognize each individual type of appliance being used. I would like to know if wavelet packet decomposition in Matlab be able to do such task. If so, please guide for methodology.

My input data set are the following:
1. The total power consumption of appliances (turning on/off randomly).
2. Power consumption of each individual appliance at the same time frame. That is, the sum of data for each appliance is equal to the total power consumption data in item 1.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The data resolution is 3 sec/sample.

Comment: Sounds a lot too complicated. Wouldn't it be easier to first construct a list of all possible combinations of appliances, sorted by their total sum of power consumption. Then for any given power consumption you can just search this list using some `±Watts` criterion that yields the results that are near to the actual consumption?